# Showing Response Status - Uploading Image using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

What I'm trying to do is download some image from a URL then upload it to WordPress post, my form below:

```
<form method="post" id="upload">
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>

<label>File Name</label>
<input type="text" id="filename_<?php echo $row->id;?>" name="data[<?php echo $row->id;?>][filename]" value="<?php echo $file_name;?>" />

<label>Title</label>
<input type="text" id="title_<?php echo $row->id;?>" name="data[<?php echo $row->id;?>][title]" value="<?php echo $title;?>" />

<?php endforeach;?> 
<button name="act" value="savepost">Save</button>
</form>
<!-- showing result here -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

So, then when click Save button... the action will call **function prc_upload()**

```
function prc_upload() {
   $posts = $_POST['data']; 
   foreach ($posts as $post) {
   $filename  = $post['filename'];
   $title     = $post['title'];
   // Process uplaoding here
   // Process uplaoding here
   // Process uplaoding here
   if (!$fileSaved) {
      $result = $filename.' Can not saved !!';
   } else {
      $result = filename' Saved Succesfuly!!';
   }
}
```

How to use jquery to show response result when Save button clicked..

Comment: `$_POST` does not have the file data. It is `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

append your img  to html

like

```
$($post).each(function(){
$('#placeIDwhereYouWantToShowImg').append('<img src='+this.imgsrc+' class="if any"/>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your form has enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute.

```
$new_post = wp_insert_post($post_array);
if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
            }
             if ($_FILES) {
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                    }
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $new_post );
                }   
            }
            if ($attach_id > 0){

                update_post_meta($new_post,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
            }
```